# Android WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS Android Api level 30 (Android 11) doesn't work

Tags: android

When setting flags in activities on android api level 30 (android 11) as window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS), the window doesn't extend to nav bar and status bar. It does nothing.

Comment: on which API level does it work for you last?

Comment: on api level 29 work like charm

Comment: Did you find a solution? FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS was working fine on Android 10 but not on Android 11

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do to fix that

Add **CoordinatorLayout** as root layout on layout file with id **container**.
then add this code on top of Activity (onCreate)

```
findViewById(R.id.container).setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```